# A good collaborative filtering/matching/recommendation library for Python/Django?

Tags: python, django, recommendation-engine, matching, collaborative-filtering

I'm looking for a library I can use to match my users to other Django models based on answers to questions-- also my own django model.

So I'd like something customizable, with good documentation/support, and hopefully not too hard to implement!

Does anyone have any good recommendations? I've looked over Crab and Django-recommender, but neither seem to be very well documented.

basically what I have is two survey applications, with corresponding, but not identical, questions and answers. E.g. a question in app1 could be "how many nights a week do you drink?" and a question in app2 could be "how many nights a week do you expect to drink?", with a foreign key to the first question in the instance. I want to take the responses to these questions and use them to pair users from each set with each other, to give the users in group 2 recommendations based on what the users in group 1 already use.

Comment: "match my users to other Django models based on answers to questions"?  Can you explain this?

Comment: Can you please **update** the question to contain all the facts in one, easy-to-read place?

Comment: Colleen, it would be useful to post the relevant models to give a good idea of their structure. Off the top of my head I don't know of an existing library to do what you want, mostly because it seems it would end up being too specific to an implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They covered this subject in the free Stanford ML class. Check the videos for chapter XVI at http://www.ml-class.org/course/video/preview_list

Although the implementation discussed is Matlab/Octave it should be not difficult to implement in Python, even easier if you are using Numpy

Answer (score 0):

There are some good books out there on the subject of social media combined with Python.

- http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010203.do
- http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920020424.do

Answer (score 0):

A very flexible solution that works in any coding language (including Python) is the **[Abracadabra Recommender API](https://www.abracadabra-recommender.com)**.

Basically it is a *Recommender Algorithms as a Service* library. The setup is very straightforward: you only need to send HTTP calls (which you can do with Django) to the API endpoint url to train your model and to receive recommendations. [View the docs how](https://www.abracadabra-recommender.com/docs/#page-top).

With the Abracadabra Recommender API, when using `Python`, you first add data to your model:

```
# These code snippets use an open-source library. http://unirest.io/python
response = unirest.post("https://noodlio-abracadabra-recommender-systems-v1.p.mashape.com/add/subjects?recommenderId=rec1&subjectId=See+docs",
  headers={
    "X-Mashape-Key": "<required>",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
)
```

Then you train the model by rating or liking subjects (for instance movies):

```
# These code snippets use an open-source library. http://unirest.io/python
response = unirest.post("https://noodlio-abracadabra-recommender-systems-v1.p.mashape.com/rate/subject?recommenderId=rec1&subjectId=gameofthrones&subjectWeight=10&userId=user1",
  headers={
    "X-Mashape-Key": "<required>",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
)
```

Once done, then you receive recommendations based on Content-Based, Collaborative or Hybrid filtering as follows:

```
# These code snippets use an open-source library. http://unirest.io/python
response = unirest.post("https://noodlio-abracadabra-recommender-systems-v1.p.mashape.com/recommend?method=content&recommenderId=rec1&userId=user1",
  headers={
    "X-Mashape-Key": "<required>",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
)
```

You can view more example in other languages, including `Angular`, `React`, `Javascript`, `NodeJS`, `Curl`, `Java`, `Python`, `Objective-C`, `Ruby`, `.NET`... on the [API homepage](https://market.mashape.com/noodlio/abracadabra-recommender-systems).